# Chart group lines in multiple groups in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2014, ssrs-2016

In SSDT 2014 there is some lines in ultiple groups that show group bound:

[image]

but in SSDT 2016 there is not such this lines. How I can add them?
[image]

Thanks

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue. I even converted a report from SSRS 2012 to SSDT 2016, and it worked fine. I don’t have SSDT 2014 installed anywhere. Have you tried rebuilding this chart from scratch?

Comment: In most scenarios, the result seen in the Preview tab in SSDT is irrelevant.  Will your users use SSDT to view reports?  Does this issue occur in the Reporting Services web portal (or wherever you are deploying your reports)?

Comment: @MikeHoney Yes it occure. When I deploy my reports it show like before (same as SSDT)

Comment: @R.Richards I rebuild and deploy it many times

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution is going to seem counter-intuitive but based on what I'm seeing I believe it will work. The lines you're seeing there that are missing in SSRS 2016 are called the Major Tick Mark lines. In SSRS 2014, the default LineStyle appears to be "Default". When I opened Report Builder for SSRS 2016, the default value was "None". My guess is there is a mapping that if it's default in 2014 (i.e., "Default") that this will map to the default in 2016 (i.e., "None").

To fix this, open your report in SSDT 2014 or SSDT 2016 and change the MajorTickMarks LineStyle to "Solid". As the MajorTickMarks LineStyle of Solid exists in both SSRS 2014 and SSRS 2016, it should carry over from one server to another.

If that doesn't work, I would recommend downloading the SSRS 2016 Report Builder and using that to set the LineStyle to "Solid" and the re-loading the report on the 2016 server.

Below are screenshots of the default LineStyle values for the MajorTickMarks when you create a new report in Report Builder 3.0 for 2012/2014 versus Report Builder for 2016.

[image: Default LineStyle values for different Report Builder versions]

Comment: I'm referencing SSRS Report Builder in my answer above rather than SSDT. I don't have SSDT installed, but when I've seen it in the past, the properties panes for SSDT and BIDS have usually mirrored the Report Builder properties. Let me know if your SSDT pane is significantly different.